# C# MVC - Database fields not loading using a JSON GET request

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Recently I start programming using ASP.NET MVC in C#. I followed a tutorial but for some reason my code doesn't work while in the tutorial it does.

What I am trying to do is do a a-synchronous loading of database table values while the users can also (while waiting for the values to load) insert values into the database.

The loading is being done with a JSON `GET` request in the html of the page where they can insert values as well.

The `ActionResult` in the controller that handles the output list and returns the JSON value does it work fine (tested it with debugging), however the javascript code (the `GET`) in the html never gets launched so I never see the data of the database in my HTML.

When I put a breakpoint at the Javascript part in the HTML it says the following:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. no executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line.

All the associated code is listed below:

The HTML page (`EnterCustomer`):

```
@model HelloWorld2.ViewModel.CustomerViewModel
@using HelloWorld2.Models;

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EnterCustomer</title>

</head>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<body>
    <div>         
         @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit","Customer",FormMethod.Post)) 
        { 

            <i>Customer Name</i> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.customer.CustomerName) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.customer.CustomerName)  <br /> 
            <i>Customer Code</i>  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.customer.CustomerCode) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.customer.CustomerCode)  <br />            

    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit"  />

        }

        <br />

        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <br />

        <div id="status"></div>
        <table id="tbl">
          <tr>
            <td>Customer Code</td>
            <td>Customer Name</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
          <script language="javascript">

              $("#status").text("Loading...");             
              $.get("getCustomers", null, BindData);  

              function BindData(Customers)
              {

                  var tbl = $("#tbl");  //reference van table (de id(#) - tbl)
                  //for loop om table te laten zien met alle databaae rows
                  for (var j = 0; j < Customers.lenght ; j++)
                  {
                      var newRow = "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + Customers[j].CustomerCode + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + Customers[j].CustomerName + "</td>" +
                       "</tr>";
                      tbl.append(newRow); //deze row(s) wordt aan de table object verbonden middels append
                  }
                  $("#status").text("");
              }
          </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `CustomerController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HelloWorld2.Models;
using HelloWorld2.DataAccessLayer;
using HelloWorld2.ViewModel; 
using System.Threading;

namespace HelloWorld2.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customer
        public ActionResult Load()
        {
            Customer obj = new Customer {CustomerCode="1001",CustomerName="Nicolas" };

            if (Request.QueryString["Type"] == "HTML")
            {
                return View("Customer", obj);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Enter()
        {
            CustomerViewModel obj = new CustomerViewModel();

            obj.customer = new Customer(); 

            return View("EnterCustomer", obj);            
        }

        public ActionResult getCustomers()    
        {
            CustomerDataAccessLayer dal = new CustomerDataAccessLayer(); 
            List<Customer> customerscoll = dal.Customers.ToList<Customer>();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            return Json(customerscoll, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
        }

        public ActionResult Submit()
        {
            Customer obj = new Customer();
            obj.CustomerName = Request.Form["Customer.CustomerName"]; 
            obj.CustomerCode = Request.Form["Customer.CustomerCode"]; 

            CustomerViewModel vm = new CustomerViewModel();

            if (ModelState.IsValid) 
            {
                CustomerDataAccessLayer Dal = new CustomerDataAccessLayer();
                Dal.Customers.Add(obj); 
                Dal.SaveChanges(); 

                vm.customer = new Customer();
            }
            else
            {
                vm.customer = obj;
            }

            List<Customer> customerscollectie = dal.Customers.ToList<Customer>(); 
            vm.customers = customerscollectie;

            return View("EnterCustomer", vm); 
        }
    }
}
```

The `CustomerDataAccessLayer` that is being referenced to in the controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using HelloWorld2.Models;

namespace HelloWorld2.DataAccessLayer
{   
    public class CustomerDataAccessLayer : DbContext 
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("tblCustomer");
        }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Some additional points:

- Already tried to clear the DLL and such.
- The `ActionResult GetCustomers` is the action which this question is related to.
- When I put a debug point in the HTML page at  `$("#status").text("Loading...");` then I get the same breakpoint error, though the text loading IS displayed in the html.. (so it does get there).
- The action result `GetCustomers` is being fired, when I load the page I get to see Loading... for the thread.sleep amount of time, when that is finished it only shows the table headers and not the data in it.
- I checked the connection and data in the database table and it seems to be fine, when I debug the `ActionResult GetCustomers` then the list is also being filled with the right amount of records. It seems the JSON does not return the values..

I hope my question is clear. I am just a beginner at ASP.NET MVC and C# for that matter so over-explaining it never hurts ;)

Comment: You can't debug JavaScript or jQuery code in Visual studio. These are client side languages. You will have to debug it in the Browser. by typing 'debugger;' under/before the JavaScript Line you want to stop at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I put a debug point in the HTML page at 
>   $("#status").text("Loading..."); then I get the same breakpoint error,
>   though the text loading IS displayed in the html.. (so it does get
>   there).

You can't debug jQuery by putting Breakpoint in Visual Studio.
It might be possible with a Plugin.

But because jQuery, JavaScript are client side Technologies it is better to debug in Browser.

All Browsers have Dev-Tools, you can access them in Chrome and FireFox by pressing `F12`. For FireFox you can install FireBug aswell

Type 'debugger' above the line of jQuery you want to debug.

Go back to browser. Press F12 and refresh your page.

so e.g.

```
function BindData(Customers)
{
debugger;
......

}



function BindData(Customers)
{
// Browser will stop Execution here:
// In Chrome You can step through code by pressing `F10`
// And continue by pressing `F8`

debugger;

//Display a variable/ string / object in console use console.log('Hello World');
// This will display the Customers Object in Console


console.log(Customers); 

// So by above line you can check if customers are returned from server
```

**Browser Console:**

[image]

**ERROR:**
And the reason you are not seeing data is because you have error in your code:

```
// On this line you have error:
for (var j = 0; j < Customers.lenght ; j++)

Should be:
for (var j = 0; j < Customers.length; j++)
```

Comment: Wow.. how could I have missed that typo.. Thank you a lot! Also for the debugging info about Javascript, didn't knew that Visual Studio couldn't handle that!